# Naming list of "status"

Tags: naming-conventions

Oh dear, the time has come for me to iterate through a list of 'status' objects. When I have a list of objects I like to name it the plural form of the name of the objects it contains unless the objects are data types like strings: for example, a list of 'dog' objects would be 'dogs'.

What do you call a list of 'status' objects? Most dictionaries seem to say the plural is the same as the singular, 'status', but that won't work as there would be a naming conflict.

Comment: Just use "statuses" and move on.  You have more important things to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Singular**: status

**Plural**: statuses

Dictionary definitions are less important than if someone will understand the code you've written, in a year's time or ten year's time. Everyone will understand that. Like Richie commented, move on with your life, you're gonna have bigger problems to solve.